# Excel-VBA: Loop to highlight cells

Tags: excel, vba

The second half of my code (a loop) needs to highlight cells if they are not equal to another worksheet. I am getting a error on the varSheetB line under the "else" section of the loop. I believe I am using the wrong syntax to tell it to highlight those cells.

This should be an easy fix. Can someone please provide the correct syntax for telling it to highlight the cells under the "else" portion of the loop?

```
For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' Cells are identical.
            ' Do nothing
        Else
            ' Cells are different.
            ' Highlight different cells yellow.
            varSheetB.Range.(iRow & iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow
End Sub
```

Edit: Adding the full code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()

    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long

    strRangeToCheck = "A12:G150"
    Debug.Print Now

    varSheetA = Worksheets("Main").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    varSheetB = Worksheets("Discrepancy Compare").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
    Debug.Print Now

    For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
            If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
                ' Cells are identical.
                ' Do nothing.
            Else
                ' Cells are different.
                ' Highlight different cells yellow.
                varSheetB.Range.(iRow & iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a "period" after Range. before the Parenthesis. That will give you an error.. Edit, also, you may want to use Cells instead of Range if you are using Numbers for the Row and Cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Tested

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()
    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    strRangeToCheck = "A12:G150"
    varSheetA = Worksheets("Main").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    varSheetB = Worksheets("Discrepancy Compare").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
    For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
            If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) <> varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
                ' Cells are different.
                ' Highlight different cells yellow.
                Worksheets("Discrepancy Compare").Cells(iRow + 11, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo. I tried your suggestion and I it is throwing an "object required" error on the 6th line.

Comment: instead of & between iRow and iCol put a comma ,

Comment: Hi LearnAsWeGo, I get the same "object required" error when using a comma.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a tested code. You can not change the color using a range stored inside an Array. You must write the worksheet name to change the color. Weird.

Comment: I have done a quick edit, to color the correct Cell you must add the difference in cells to iRow and iCol depending on where the Range starts if it is not on A1. Example, if the range is starts on A12, you must add + 11 to iRow and +0 to iCol ( 0 because it starts on Column A, if it started on Column C, you would have to add +2 to iCol). This will ensure to color the correct Cell.

Comment: Perfect!..works like a charm. I really appreciate it Ricardo!

Answer (score 1):

Range is not `Range.()` it is `Range()`.

But, range will expect a Character string for the column and you are passing a number.

In this instance use Cells() which will allow the use of a number for the column:

```
varSheetB.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
```

But you need to ensure the `iRow` and `iCol` do not start at 0, depending on your setup and how the arrays were filled you may start at 0.

Also, unless you start loading the array from A1 the column and Rows will be off.

Comment: Ah ok. Let me actually post the full code to provide more clarity.